# What is the expected number of trials before x successes with variable probability?

Tags: probability, geometric-series, negative-binomial

I am trying to calculate the probability of reaching n successes on a trial, *knowing that a failure will increase success chance.*

In simpler term, what is the mean number of trials before we reach $x$ successes with $p = min(y + wF, 1)$? *(with $F$ being the number of failures)*

This does include the fact that after a certain number of failures, success is guaranteed ($p>1$).

I've tried to inspire myself from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/745002/calculate-number-of-successes-after-t-trials-with-linearly-increasing-probabilit), but I don't want $F$ to reset upon success.

Comment: Confusing.  Looks like you intend that if $wy = q$ and $F$ is the number of failures that have already occurred, then chance of failure on next trial is $qF$.  If this is wrong, please advise.  If this is right, then what is the chance of failure on the very 1st trial?

Comment: Re previous comment - perhaps I am misinterpreting your mathematical intent.  Please edit your question, using [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to show math.  Also, re previous comment, I question whether my interpretation is tenable.  Besides the problem  of determining chance of failure on 1st trial, chance of failure on any trial must be $\leq 1$.  However, the expression $qF$ may **exceed** $1$.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks for your comment, I'll try to update my question to make it more clear. Also, correcting my typo: $p$ is the chance of success, defined by a base probability $y$ plus $wF$. Not multiplied.

Comment: Then, how do you prevent $y + wF$ from exceeding $1$?

Comment: @user2661923 I can't, kind of on purpose: after a certain number of failures, success is guaranteed. With $y=0.5$ and $w=0.5$, success is guaranteed after one success. I don't know (and hope) if it breaks the math to have $p>1$ however....

Comment: You could simply specify $p = \min(y + wF, 1)$, if that accurately represents your intent.

Comment: @user2661923 that does, thank you! I'll update my post.